# wordpress empty posts after migration

Tags: wordpress

I uploaded my website from local host to a server and I had the following problems:

- The posts in the front end are displayed correctly but in the back end are empty.
- the accents and some caracters are displayed wrongly. If I do a new post they are showed correctly.

Any idea of what can be? Couldn't find nothing in internet.
Thank you!